# Received message type 700 while waiting for activation message when trying to create a Sawtooth Test Network from the documentation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-sawtooth

I'm new to sawtooth and I have been reading the documentation and following the example to get a Sawtooth Test Network.
I'm using the docker version and following [this](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/1.2/app_developers_guide/creating_sawtooth_network.html) page.

since I'm using the PoET consensus algorithm, [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core/blob/main/docker/compose/sawtooth-default-poet.yaml) is my docker-compose.

I'm using:
**Docker version 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu2~20.04.1**
and
**docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown**

after running the command:

```
docker-compose -f sawtooth-default-poet.yaml up
```

there are some log lines that I will be attaching [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p00io1z51sh1c2n/output.txt?dl=0) and after that the logs keep repeating the line:

```
Received message type 700 while waiting for activation message
```

if I run docker ps -a
it shows me that all the containers related to this docker-compose are running.

if I move on with the documentation(step4) and just enter the command to enter into the sawtooth-shell-default container:

```
docker exec -it sawtooth-shell-default bash
```

and then proceed to run the command:

```
curl http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/peers
```

it will return an empty data list as bellow:[running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxLib.png)

the documentation specifies:

> "Repeat the query until you see output that resembles the
> following example"

but after 45 minutes I have come to the conclusion that is probably of no use since the output of the command:

```
curl http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/peers
```

won't change and will still return an empty data list.

can someone help me solve this problem?

thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

it could be a problem with the endpoint that you're using.

Have you tried to call http://rest-api-0:8008/peers instead of http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/peers ?

Because "sawtooth-rest-api-default-0" is the name of docker container meanwhile "rest-api-0" is the name of the service in the docker-compose.yaml.